# How to remove intermediary outputs in when looping through a key with multiple values so that I can save it in a HTML file

Tags: python, html, function, loops, dictionary

I grouped all the values with the same key and successfully performed the calculation I wanted. Whenever I print the calculations, I observe all these intermediary outputs where the program is iterating. I only need the final outputs. I have tried shifting the print function outside the iteration, but it only outputs calculations from the final column. The project only allows me to import CSV.
Can I add any line of code to it so that the programme iterates through all the values simultaneously?

My code:

```
import csv
def html_stats(csv_file: str, html_file: str, title: str = None):
   grouped_data = {}
   with open(csv_file, 'r') as cal_file:
      reader = csv.DictReader(cal_file)
      for i in reader:
          for k, v in i.items():
             grouped_data.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
             for i in range(len(grouped_data)):
                 keys = list(grouped_data.keys())[i]
                 calc = grouped_data.get(keys)
                 int_stats = [int(m) for m in calc]
                 max_value = max(int_stats)
                 min_value = min(int_stats)
                 mean_value = sum(int_stats) / len(int_stats)
                 s = sorted(int_stats)
                 n = len(int_stats)
                 median_value = (s[n // 2 - 1] / 2.0 + s[n // 2] / 2.0, s[n // 2])[n % 2] if n else None
                 print(max_value)
                 print(min_value)
                 print(mean_value)
                 print(median_value)
```

'''

Output when run

```
  9533
  9533
  9533.0
  9533
  9533
  9533
  and then like 50 - 60 more outputs

  the only output I need is the output below
  
  11587
  6493
  8724.35
  8539.0
  10562
  5778
  7822.3
  7668.0
  63963
  5086
  43479.25
  44933.5
```